# Show the most recent post for an author on the author page

Tags: author, author-template, list-authors

I have 6 authors in my blog page. I have profile for each of the authors. I want to show the posts of the authors dynamically under their own profile. I tried the following but it showed all posts. with this code it is showing the posts in all profiles not specific profiles. What changes should i make?

```
$current_author = get_query_var('author');
$author_posts=  get_posts( 'author='.$current_author->id.'&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC&orderby=post_date' );
if($author_posts){
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($author_posts as $author_post)  {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($author_post->ID).'">'.$author_post- >post_title.'</a>   </li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

I use the following function to show the Image and description about the author

```
function ajaxified_function() 
{ 
$post = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
$feat_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
$desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description",$post->ID);
    if( is_array( $desc_values ) )
    {
        foreach($desc_values as $key => $value );
    }
echo '<div id="bloggers_feat_img">'.$feat_image.'</div>'.$post->post_.'<div class="bloggers_title">'.$post->post_title.'</div><div id="bloggers_desc">'.$value.'</div><br/><div id="bloggers_postContent">'.$post->post_content.'</div><div>'.$author.'</div>';
die();
}
```

Following js is which I use to show the above in a lightbox when clicking on a link

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function (){
 jQuery('#options_to_connect a').on('click',function(event){         
event.preventDefault();
var post_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('class'); 
jQuery.ajax({  
type: "POST",                  
url:  'http:www.myblog.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
   data: 'action=ajaxified_function&post_id='+post_id,    
   success: function (msg) {                                        
       jQuery('#cboxLoadedContent').html(msg);
   },
   error: function () {                  
  alert('Error');               
   }  
  });           
  });       
});
```

Comment: Stop deleting your questions. Improve them instead!

Comment: Sorry about that.. I am not getting any response.. Thats y

Comment: The correct reaction to a lack of responses is improvement, not deletion.

Comment: I dont knw how more to improve...This is what I have and I think I am clear about my question

Comment: Read [1](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/), [2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Can you please give me an answer for my question?

Comment: I answered that in comment on the predecessor of this question.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see any answer there....!!!

Comment: I have Improved the question. Please see that

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Basic debugging...

```
$current_author = get_query_var('author');
var_dump($current_author);
```

... would reveal that `$current_author` is a `string`, not an object. The problem is that you are trying to use the `string` as an `object` in the query.

```
get_posts( 'author='.$current_author->id.'&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC&orderby=post_date' );
```

Change `$current_author->id` to `$current_author` and the query works.

```
$author_posts =  get_posts( 'author='.$current_author.'&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC&orderby=post_date' );
```

Comment: It didnt work.Still It is the same. Posts are showing for all profiles

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: I ran the code I posted, and it works, assuming the `get_query_var('author')` value is set correctly. Are you sure that value is set and is correct?

Comment: I think that's where my problem is .please tell me How to set that value?

Comment: Is this the normal "author" page or something you've created?

Comment: Its a template page that I have created

Comment: How are you passing that author variable to the page? If this is something you've cooked up it won't be automatic. Why aren't you using the normal author pages?